# The product of the slopes of the common tangents to the parabolas $y=x^2+1$ and $y=-x^2-1$

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives

> Consider all lines that are simultaneously tangent to the parabolas $y = x^2 + 1$ and $y = −x^2 − 1$. What's the product of these lines' slopes?

Taking the derivative, I found two slopes, whose product is $-4$. The correct solution, however, is $-1$.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the source of the problem?

Comment: It would appear that your answer is correct.

Comment: @quasi Sorry, I've translated incorrectly "slope" as "angular coefficient". Please see my updated question. The source (in Portuguese) can be [found here, it's the question 3.24](https://www.ime.usp.br/~ikemoto/2018-2453-Lista1-bcc.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangent line to a function $f$ at $x=x_0$ has equation $$y=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$$

Therefore the tangents to the first parabola are given by
$$y=2x_0x-x_0^2+1$$
and the tangents to the second one by $$y=-2x_1x+x_1^2-1$$

The equations match if and only if $x_0=\pm 1$ and $x_1=\mp1$.

Therefore the product of the slopes is $2\times (-2)=-4.$

Comment: Thank you, it seems that the problem set answer is wrong.

Comment: @rodorgas you're welcome. This can happen.